# variable with a variable substring in bash

Tags: bash, variable

In bash, I have defined

```
chg_Li=3
chg_Na=9
```

Now I want to call `$chg_$i` where `i` is in a for loop, looping over `Li` and `Na`.

What is the correct syntax to call `$chg_$i`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` or indirection:

```
eval echo \$chg_$i
```

or

```
varname=$chg_$i
echo ${!varname}
```

Comment: Preferably indirection.  When using `eval`, your first thought should be "If I'm using `eval`, I probably need to rethink my approach" in nearly all cases.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned, you can use indirection for this:

```
$ chg_Li=3
$ chg_Na=9
$ post_fix=(Li Na)
$ for j in ${post_fix[@]}; do chg="chg_$j"; echo "${!chg}"; done;
3
9
```